# XSLT syntax for extracting text and putting it elsewhere?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML document that looks roughly like this:

```
<doc>
 <header> 
  Here is a header thing. 
 </header>  
 <docBody>
  Here is a long string of text in which other tags like <person>Me</person> appear. 
 </docBody> 
</doc>
```

My XSL looks about like this:

```
<xsl:template match="header"> <!--get header stuff--> 
 <myHeader>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>  
 </myHeader> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="docBody"> <!--get body stuff--> 
 <myBody> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 <myBody>  
</xsl:template>
```

Output is roughly:

```
<myHeader> 
   Here is a header thing. 
</myHeader> 

<myBody>
  Here is a long string of text in which other tags like Me appear. 
</myBody>
```

Where the `<person>` tag disappears. I noticed that I can do

```
<xsl:template match="person">
 <myPerson>
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </myPerson> 
</xsl:template>
```

But then, for reasons I don't understand, I get this output when the php simplexml_load_string() function parses it, probably because it doesn't include child elements:

```
<myBody>
 Here is a long string of text in which other tags like appear. 
</myBody>
```

Which is mysteriously missing the text between the `<person>` tags.

What I want to output instead is:

```
<myBody> 
 Here is a long string of text in which other tags like Me appear. 
</myBody> 

<person> 
 Me
</person>
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you describe is unlikely to be produced by the templates you show and describe.  From the templates you show, I would expect the output of the docBody template to be

```
<myBody>
Here is a long string of text in which other tags like 
<myPerson>
Me
</myPerson>
appear.
</myBody>
```

I suspect there is something relevant you are not telling us.

But the behavior you say you want can be achieved with:

```
<xsl:template match="docBody">
  <myBody><xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/></myBody>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person">
  <person><xsl:apply-templates/></person>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You're right, it was a php xml parsing function that removed child elements. Edited question.